# Finding out lengths of days runs selected form raster

Tags: r, raster

Previously, I had a rasterbrick called "xxx" (whose details are not necessary) which I selected a Rasterlayer from. The rasterlayer ("Y") was selected through following code:

```
 ff<-function(x){
 y<-x > 1
 n<- ave(y,cumsum(y == 0), FUN = cumsum)
 sum(n >= 10)
 }
 Y<-calc(xxx,ff)
```

It means, that Y gives amount of runs greater or equal 10 (in this case, 10 days) for every single grid point. The layer has got following description:

```
 class      : RasterBrick 
 dimensions : 201, 241, 48441, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
 resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
 extent     : -15.125, 45.125, 24.875, 75.125  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
 source: E:/diplomka/Y_fin.grd 
 names      : layer 
 min values :     0 
 max values :   234
```

Now, I would like to somehow figure out the average lenghts of runs (as they can be 10 or more days long). So I guess I should multiply the amount of runs (brick Y) by the amount of total days included in those runs for every grid point. I hope its understandable. Every help very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

```
ff<-function(x){
    y <- x > 1
    n <- ave(y, cumsum(y == 0), FUN = cumsum)
    mean(n[n >= 10])
}
```